# Trying to initialise all joysticks available and putting their names in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have been trying to make a program that  initialises all joysticks available and puts their names in a list. It gives the following error:

```
joysticks[x].init()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I thought that that wouldn't be possible since the for-loop stops when there are no more joysticks. 
Can someone spot the problem?
Thanks in advance,
Adutchman

```
import pygame,sys
#pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1))
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Ets2 Button Admin")
window.geometry('500x300')

pygame.joystick.init()
pygame.display.init()
#Initialises pygame
j_name =[]
def controlcheck():
    count = pygame.joystick.get_count()
    if count == 0:
        lbl = Label(window, text="There is no controller connected to the PC, please connect a controller")
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

    elif count > 0:
        lbl = Label(window, text="Connected controllers:")
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
        for x in range(count):
            joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(x)]
            joysticks[x].init()
            j_name = [joysticks[x].get_name()]
        lbl = Label(window, text=f"{j_name}")
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)
    window.after(500,controlcheck)
controlcheck()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the code has the joystick in a list, but each time the list is being re-created with a single element.  So when `x` is zero, it's OK.  But on the second iteration, `joysticks` is still only a list of 1 element, but the code requests the second element (because `x` == 1).

```
    for x in range(count):
        joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(x)]
        joysticks[x].init()
```

I guess you meant to create a list of joysticks:

```
    joysticks = []
    for i in range( count ):
        joysticks.append( pygame.joystick.Joystick( i ) )
        joysticks[i].init()
```

You could have also used `joysticks[-1].init()` to always get the last element, but that would not have highlighted this error.

Style note: Generally the convention is to use the variable `i` for a simple loop iterator.  (Sometimes `j` and `k` too, for nested loops).  This matters somewhat because other software engines will more quickly be able to read the code, because it conforms to the way the majority of people write code.  Any *you* will be able to more-quickly understand their code.  But ultimately, it's your code, so write it how you like.

Comment: Thank you for the responce and the explaination. As for the use of i/x, I defaulted to x because of math class and you're quite right. Your solution only works partially though, since now, when I print j_name in a label, it only shows one joystick, while I can detect both individually when i unplug one or the other.

Comment: Edit: when I use the same technique for j_name (so j_name.append(joysticks[i].get_name()) ) It works fine.